# Unable to compile Siri extension in Swift 2.3

Tags: swift, xcode8, siri, sirikit, swift2

I want to integrate the Siri/Intent extension in my App, currently based on Swift 2.3. I am using the Xcode 8 beta 6 build.

The app fails to even compile, giving out errors as

---

> Type 'IntentHandler' does not conform to protocol 'INSendMessageIntentHandling'
>
> Protocol requires function 'handle(sendMessage:completion:)' with type '(sendMessage: INSendMessageIntent, completion: (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) -> Void'
>
> Objective-C method 'handleWithSendMessage:completion:' provided by method 'handle(sendMessage:completion:)' does not match the requirement's selector ('handleSendMessage:completion:')
>
> ---

Even the sample app from Apple, UnicornChat fails to compile with the same errors. I did change the **SWIFT_VERSION** flag to **Yes**, to support Swift 2.3

Sample Code:

```
func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
        let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .Success, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response)
    }
```

This fails with the error above.

Anyone has an idea on how to make Siri work in Swift 2.3?

Comment: Have you implemented "func handle(sendMessage intent: ..."? If so, please show us that.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Please check the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, this helped

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/174455#174455

We need to explicitly define the @objc method signatures with the Swift ones. As in the following works.

```
@objc (handleSendMessage:completion:)
func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
 //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Xcode 8 beta 6 has been updated to Swift 3 and the call back needs @escaping added to the method:

```
func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Swift.Void) {  
  //..  
}
```

If the Siri delegate methods have been updated to Swift 3 (as appears to be the case) then I am afraid you will have to use Swift 3 as well, or an older version of the SDK.

Comment: OP is using swift 2.3.

Comment: I realize that - but it looks like the delegate methods have been revised to Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

While compiling your code with Swift 2.3, you need to set **Use Legacy Swift Language Version** to **YES** for Siri and SiriUI targets.

Also, when **IntentHandler** and **IntentViewController** are created, methods might have been created in Swift 3 (as happened to me). So convert the classes to Swift 2.3, and use **@objc** method signatures along with the delegates.

For **IntentHandler**,

```
@objc (handleSendMessage:completion:)
func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
}

@objc (handleSearchForMessages:completion:)
func handle(searchForMessages intent: INSearchForMessagesIntent, completion: (INSearchForMessagesIntentResponse) -> Void) {
}

@objc (handleSetMessageAttribute:completion:)
func handle(setMessageAttribute intent: INSetMessageAttributeIntent, completion: (INSetMessageAttributeIntentResponse) -> Void) {
}
```

For **IntentViewController**,

```
@objc (configureWithInteraction:context:completion:)
func configureWithInteraction(interaction: INInteraction!, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: ((CGSize) -> Void)!) {
}
```

Hope this helped.